# Прокачка "скила" перед ГИА

Tags: общие-вопросы

ГИА не за горами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, сайты, где можно по тренировать знание Русского языка. (Что в моём случае необходимо!!!)

Answer (score 4):

Сайтов,действительно, много, но, как верно отметила Noir, в тестах много ошибок. Почему бы Вам не выйти на сайт fipi.ru, это официальный сайт разработчиков экзаменационных материалов. Там есть сотни заданий по каждому разделу, а еще открытый сегмент заданий, которые будут в этом году на экзамене.

Answer (score 1):

Их тысячи, вот ,например, http://uchimcauchitca.blogspot.ru/2013/05/2013_6481.html

Answer (score 1):

Увы, таковых немного. [Здесь](http://silinasv.blogspot.com/2010/11/blog-post.html) перечислены некоторые. В качестве отсебятины добавлю к списку, расположенному по ссылке, еще несколько пунктов: [Грамматический справочник по русскому языку](http://www.orfo.ru/Tutorial/Html/Tutorial.htm); [Балашова Л. В., Дементьев В. В. "Курс русского языка"](http://www.licey.net/russian/map); [портал русского языка "Ярус"](http://yarus.aspu.ru/?id=6).

На первый взгляд может показаться, что в действительности подобных ресурсов достаточно, но это только иллюзия, которая разрушается, когда вы обнаруживаете, что почти все они содержат ошибки, а потому не могут являться носителем истины в последней инстанции.

Бог в помощь.